# Как реализовать сканер элемента на веб странице на предмет изменений в самом элементе?

Tags: javascript

Задача: раз в 15 минут скачивать страницу, находить в ней нужный элемент select, и, если в нём появились элементы option – отправить уведомление на эл. почту и прекратить дальнейший мониторинг.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значит, надо раз в 15 минут скачивать страницу, находить в ней нужный элемент `select`, и, если в нём появились элементы `option` – отправить уведомление на эл. почту и прекратить дальнейший мониторинг.

Можно, наверное, сделать расширение браузера, на JS, но тогда придётся постоянно держать открытым браузер и не выключать компьютер – этот вариант не будем рассматривать.

Понадобится сервер, на котором по расписанию ([cron](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/admin/cron.html)) будет запускаться скрипт, выполняющий проверку.

Серверный скрипт можно написать и на JS (на сервере должен присутствовать nodejs), и на любом другом языке: php, perl, python, ruby – что вам ближе. Как сделать на php – замечательно описал [[@Etki](/users/16095/etki)](/users/16095/etki). Я бы так и делал.

Наконец, есть «готовенький» вариант (не пробовал) – сервис [ChangeDetect](http://www.changedetect.com/) с вроде бы бесплатным режимом.

Answer (score 0):

> Я так понимаю реализуется подобное с помощью JS

нет, если только не имеется в виду серверный js

на php - cron + guzzle/guzzle + symfony/dom-crawler + swiftmailer/swiftmailer

Answer (score 0):

Ну если есть желание немного погрузится например в C#, то можно делать парсинг страницы, находить нужное, сохранить и потом при каждом следующем парсинге сравнивать. 
Как примеры:

[пример 1](http://powercodx.blogspot.com/2013/06/c-sharp-parsing-web-site.html)

[пример 2](http://csharpprogramming.ru/web/poisk-html-elementa-s-atributom-id)

[Пример 3](http://forums.asp.net/t/2008862.aspx?How+to+read+HTML+element+value+using+c+Code+)

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд для мониторинга изменения элемента лучше всего подойдет классный инструмент на php: [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Он позволяет работать с элементами DOM примерно так, как это делает JQuery. А для периодичности надо cron.